# Matplotlib Line Chart Not Plotting Correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to compare the price of NEAR with the NASDAQ index. I have the following code:

```
plt.figure()

#define width of candlestick elements
width = .5
width2 = .09
start = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
near = web.get_data_yahoo('NEAR-USD', start, end)
idix = web.get_data_yahoo('^IXIC', start, end)

near['Adj Close'].plot(label='NEAR',title='Adj Close');
idix['Adj Close'].plot(label='IDIX', title='Adj Close');

plt.legend();
plt.show()
```

But for some reason, it is not plotting correctly. See attached image. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Have you compared the data from each? This is what happens when the magnitudes of the numbers are significantly different. You can use the second axis to display the data, or there can be a 'log' format if it is not monetary.

Comment: Try this: `idix['Adj Close'].plot(label='IDIX', title='Adj Close',secondary_y=True);`

Comment: Okay, when i do that, I only see the label for one of the two in the legend, do you know why that may be?

Comment: Try this: `near['Adj Close'].plot(label='NEAR',title='Adj Close',legend=True);idix['Adj Close'].plot(label='IDIX', title='Adj Close',secondary_y=True, legend=True)`